# Adding to array only adds 1 value, then stops

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a function that converts a TCHAR array to individual arrays, splitting it by a comma, then add a null terminator character (I think that is the name, it is '\0' in regEx). (Basically, the .split function in java, + a '\0'), but the code is only adding one value, then stops. It is very weird, as I believe this worked ~3-4 months ago, but not now for a reason unknown.

I would imagine it is an issue with my conceptual understanding of C++, as it is very much not my language of choice.

My apologies that this is basically asking someone to "fix my homework" (not actually homework, just a side project). However, I can't find the issue and have been unable to find the error for a few hours now, again probably due to me being dumb with C++.

Code Sample:

```
TCHAR** schemeValueToArray(TCHAR* buffer, DWORD size) {
    TCHAR delim = ',';

    TCHAR** out = new TCHAR*[CURSORS_AMOUNT];
    int lastSeperator = 0;
    for (int outOn = 0; outOn < CURSORS_AMOUNT-1; outOn++) {
        // Get rest of section until end
        TCHAR* temp = new TCHAR[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (buffer[i + lastSeperator] == ',') {
                temp[i] = '\0';
                out[outOn] = temp;
                lastSeperator += i;
                lastSeperator++;
                break;
            }
            temp[i] = buffer[i + lastSeperator];
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

If you would like a bigger snippet, I can provide it.

Also, if it helps, this project once would change my mouse cursor theme when an app called AutoDarkMode requested. Making my cursor light theme during the day and dark theme at night. It would do this by copying the Registry theme value, splitting it, then putting the correct files in the correct registry spots. It was a small thing that I really liked, and now in explicitly, it has stopped.

Also, also, I am a lot more familiar with Java and Kotlin. If you are looking for ways to describe something and can relate it to something in those languages, I should be able to understand.

Thank you guys, appreciate any help!

Comment: Can't reproduce - maybe you're mixing up use of `TCHAR` and `char` somewhere?

Comment: But, overall, you're probably better off using a `std::vector` of `std::string` (or `std::wstring`) than your `TCHAR**` array.

Comment: If you could provide a sample input, that would be helpful. Because looking at the code, it's most probably something with out-of-bound indexing but without a sample input, it's hard to tell. For example, if ```size``` is the size of each array without a null terminator, you'll need to allocate ```size + 1``` when separating the arrays.

Comment: @Elliott No worries, I never downvote for such small omissions/mistakes. I was simply pointing it out. Thanks for correcting. (may also be worth noting there is not a single array used in the code to clear up misconceptions the OP has between pointer/array)

Comment: The immediate issue seems to be `temp[i] = buffer[i + lastSeperator];` likely exceeding the bounds of `buffer` -- but we can't tell from what was posted. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing the necessary details, including your MCRE, compiler warnings and sample data, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: `TCHAR` is Windows 95 technology. Leave it in the past millennium where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, I'd switch to using something like an `std::vector<std::string>` instead of pointers to pointers and such.

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> schemeValueToArray(TCHAR* buffer) {

    std::istringstream buf(buffer);

    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    std::string item;

    while (std::getline(buf, item, ',')) {
        ret.push_back(item);
    }
    return ret;
}
```